# Is there any simpler code to separate lines?

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to separate the next line and giving space.

```
String sms="Name:"+name+ System.getProperty ("line.separator")+System.getProperty   
   ("line.separator")+"ContactNumber:"+contactnumber+ System.getProperty 
   ("line.separator")+"Quantity:"+quantity+System.getProperty 
   ("line.separator")+"Number.of.Pcs:"+noofpieces+System.getProperty 
   ("line.separator")+"Date and Time:"+dateandtime
   +System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Delivary 
   Address:"+deliveryaddress;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `StringBuilder` instance and then use the new line operator appended to the `StringBuilder`. For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Name: ").append(name);
sb.append("\n"); // for a new line.
```

Whatever the case, I would strongly recommend that you use a StringBuilder to append to a very large String.

In addition, you could also use [`System.lineSeparator();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) However, that may only work in Java with the JVM with Java 7 and not in Android (so I would definitely check that out.)

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` is java 7, which android is not. Previous versions of java use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. This property is explicitly documented for android http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)

Comment: @blackpanther If you use a StringBuilder you should not concatenate values you want to append with the plus operator, as this creates another StringBuilder which is then appended. e.g. in your above example `sb.append("Name: " + name);` will be compiled to `sb.append((new StringBuilder()).append("Name: ").append(s).toString());`

Answer (score 1):

```
String sms= "Name:" + name 
  + "\nContactNumber:" + contactnumber
  + "\nQuantity:" + quantity
  + "\nNumber.of.Pcs:" + noofpieces
  + "\nDate and Time:" + dateandtime
  + "\nDelivary Address:" + deliveryaddress;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is a good practice as it will give you code that could be reused on another platform. To simplify your code, you can use TextUtils.join :

```
String sms = TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), 
    new String[] {
        "Name:" + name , 
        "ContactNumber:" + contactnumber, 
        ...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this solution

```
String format = "Name: %s%n%nContactNumber: %s%nQuantity: %s%nNumber.of.Pcs: %s%nDate and Time: %s%nDelivery Address: %s";
String sms = String.format(format, name, contactnumber, quantity, noofpieces, dateandtime, deliveryaddress);
```

The explanation of the format placeholders you find in the Javadoc for [java.util.Formater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)